# imageView.setImageBitmap(Bitmap) slows my app extremly

Tags: android, user-interface, bitmap, imageview, android-canvas

i have written a litte app that should display a tacho that gets it data about rpm... over bluetooth. when the data changes i rotate a needle and some other imageViews to display the current values on the screen.

rotate code:

```
bMapRpm=bMapcanvasBackTacho.copy(bMapcanvasBackTacho.getConfig(), true);
canvasRpm.setBitmap(bMapRpm);
canvasRpm.save();
canvasRpm.rotate((float)Rpmdegree+(float)Rpmcurrentdegree,bMapRpm.getWidth()/2,bMapRpm.getHeight()/2);
canvasRpm.drawBitmap(bMapNadel,0,0,paint);
canvasRpm.restore();
```

bMapcanvasBackTacho is just a transparent background.
bMapNadel is the bitmap of the needle.
bMapRpm is the bitmap of the canvas to draw on

to update the imageView i allways call:

```
ivNadel.setImageBitmap(bMapRpm);
```

i tryed out what slows the app by commenting parts of the code out.
after commenting the setImageBitmap() out the slow down disapeared.

doese someone know how to update the imageView in an other way or whta i could change to get it to work faster?

thx =)

Answer (score 3):

You can do two things:
First, don't call `copy()` each time you need to update the `Bitmap` this creates a new `Bitmap` and is both time and memory consuming.
Second, call `invalidate()` on the `ImageView`. This will notify the View that something has changed and it redraws itself without having to update anything else that is happening when you replace the Bitmap completely.

In the end you might even want to create your own View implementation so you can just override `onDraw()` and perform rotations there.

Comment: i tried to invalidate instead of setting a new bitmap but it is still slow and now the imageViews don't display anything =( i set the bitmaps for the imageViews once in the onCreate methode

Comment: Did you remove the `copy()`? otherwise you would still be drawing to a new bitmap and not the original one present in the `ImageView`.

Comment: hmm i'll try to implement my own view. hopefully it will help

Comment: no didn't remove the copy the problem is that the bitmaps have transparent areas. so i have to clear it in some way before redrawing. i also tried things like canvasBoost.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR); or bMapBoost.eraseColor(0); but then i get other problems like some mistake while drawing(some areas are not drawn...)

Comment: ok and even if there wouldnt be the problem with the mistakes while drawing and erasing it is still slow

Comment: I see. Well, I would recommend creating your own View-implementation then. You can start by using a regular `View` although if that is too slow you might have to look at a `SurfaceView` or even a `GLSurfaceView`. If you are developing for Honeycomb or higher, remember that you can also activate HardwareAcceleration for a drawing boost.